# Error installing Sequelize

Tags: javascript, amazon-ec2, sequelize.js

i tried installing sequelize.js on my ec2 on amazon. I simply copied and pasted entire example into my brand new app from this page. http://sequelizejs.com/articles/express

i suspect there is connection problem with sequelize.js to database. but i have no idea. would anyone have any idea?

i did install mysql and created sequelize_test database.

```
$ echo "CREATE DATABASE sequelize_test;" | mysql -uroot
$sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                     LISTEN      21836/mysqld
```

this is what i get when i run node app.js

```
/home/ubuntu/samplePg/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:274
      this.importCache[path] = defineCall(this, DataTypes)
                               ^
TypeError: object is not a function
    at module.exports.Sequelize.import (/home/ubuntu/samplePg/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:274:32)
    at /home/ubuntu/samplePg/models/index.js:14:33
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/samplePg/models/index.js:13:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.4.4",
    "jade": "*",
    "pg": "~2.8.4",
    "sequelize": "~2.0.0-beta.2",
    "lodash": "~2.4.1",
    "mysql": "~2.0.0-rc2"
  }
}
```

i have zero idea what is wrong. hope someone would have insight on this.
thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

after 3 more hours...finally found out why!!
...because i was using emacs. which produces backup files with a ~ ending
so there were index.js~ task.js~ and user.js~ in addition to the normal files.

models/index.js parses normal files AS WELL AS the backup files 
(which has the squiggly appended to the end of the file name)

ran the command at root of directory

```
find -name "*~" | xargs rm
```

and viola! i'm back in business =D

also added this code in the `.filter` condition so i don't have to worry about clearing those backup files again...

```
((file.slice(-1) !== "~") && (file.indexOf('#') !== 0))
```